# How to return multiple nodes using shortest path?

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

I'm trying to recreate this in C#:

```
    MATCH p=shortestPath((bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]-(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"}))
    RETURN p
```

But all examples i found that uses shortest path only returns a list of same type of nodes. In this example i need to return both People and Movies nodes.
So it starts something like this :

```
    var shortestPath = graphClient.Cypher
            .OptionalMatch("p = shortestPath((bacon: Person )-[*] - (meg: Person ) )")
            .Where((Person bacon) => bacon.name == "Kevin Bacon ")
            .AndWhere((Person meg) => meg.name == "Meg Ryan")
            .Return(?)
            .Results;
```

What should i write instead of question mark?

Graph looks like this:
[image]

Update :
The only information I found on neo4j client's shortest path is this [Return All Nodes in Shortest Path as Object List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583674/return-all-nodes-in-shortest-path-as-object-list) but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question - and tough to work out, I think I've got there - though - it's probably not the most performant.

As you say - the problem is multiple types - so let's get things setup, I'm using an extension method to make this look a bit nicer code wise:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this string value)
    {
        //deserialize into a 'Node' first
        var node = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(value);

        //then take the 'data' from that and 'ToObject' to the correct thing.
        return ((JObject) node.data).ToObject<T>();
    }

    private class Node{
        public object data {get;set;}
    }
}
```

The `ToObject<T>` method is what we'll use to convert our output to objects.

I've got the standard set of POCO for representing the data (albeit with bad naming conventions for the properties):

```cs
public class Movie {
    public string title {get;set;}
    public string tagline {get;set;}
}

public class Person {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public int born {get;set;}
}

public class RolesRel {
    public IEnumerable<string> roles {get;set;}
}
```

OK - now we're ready to go. I've changed the `Return` to look like this:

```cs
var shortestPath = graphClient.Cypher
     .OptionalMatch("p = shortestPath((bacon: Person)-[*]-(meg: Person ) )")
     .Where((Person bacon) => bacon.name == "Kevin Bacon")
     .AndWhere((Person meg) => meg.name == "Meg Ryan")
     .Return(p => new {
        Nodes = Return.As<IEnumerable<string>>("nodes(p)"),
        Relationships = Return.As<IEnumerable<RolesRel>>("rels(p)")
     });
```

`string` is the only universal option we've got for deserializing multiple node types. In this scenario, as the relationships are all the same, we're all good on that front to just use a POCO - but if they weren't you'd end up doing what we're doing for Nodes for them as well.

Next, I run through the results:

```cs
foreach (var result in shortestPath.Results)
{
    foreach (var node in result.Nodes)
    {
        if(node.Contains("name"))
            Console.WriteLine(node.ToObject<Person>().name);
        else if(node.Contains("title"))
            Console.WriteLine(node.ToObject<Movie>().title);
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown Node Type: " + node);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm doing a naive check here for a property name I know is in one node type, but not another - and you may want to do it another way - but this works.

Obviously - I'm just outputting to the screen - but you will have access to the object itself.